# Representing an optional value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm used to working in functional languages with monadic constructs such as Option or Optional. I'm aware of libraries like fp-ts which offer these constructs in TS/JS. However I'm interested to know how imperative developers represent optional values in typescript.

From what I can see null or undefined can both be used along with a guard e.g.

```
const user = getUser(id)

if (maybeUser) { 
  // do something
} else {
 // do something else
}
```

given this scenarios what is the correct return type for getUser? `User | null` or `User | undefined`. To me, null seems more explicit, yet undefined seems more common. I think I'm correct in saying that name?: string is a shortcut for name: string | undefined

Answer (score 0):

> when we do not assign any value to a variable, the JavaScript engine treats it as undefined. The null value is assigned by the programmer to indicate that the variable has nothing inside of it, but intends to have a value later in the program execution.

In the following link, you can find an answer to your question: https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/undefined-vs-null/

Also in the case of the elvis operator that you posted:

```
const hey = (hey?:string) => {
  console.log(typeof hey)
}
```

will be translated as:

```
declare const hey: (hey?: string | undefined) => void;
```